# env_logger initialized only once?

Tags: logging, rust

was recently exploring the use of `env_logger` library in Rust, it's a great library. I encountered, however, an issue that is related to a multithreaded scenario, where, if the logger is already initialized, the thread panics as it cannot re-initialize it. I'm getting this error

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Builder::init should not be called after logger initialized: SetLoggerError(())', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/env_logger-0.10.0/src/lib.rs:816:14
```

The question is straight-forward - how does one check if logger is already initialized, and proceed with Builder::init only in that case (so that a thread does not panic)?

Comment: Btw, today I recommend `tracing` and `tracing-subscriber` over `env-logger` (but it is still fine for simpler cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`Builder::try_init()`](https://docs.rs/env_logger/latest/env_logger/struct.Builder.html#method.try_init) instead. It returns an error instead of panicking.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was missing indeed. Also thanks for `tracing` hint